# Change carousel slider bootstrap height

Tags: html, css

I need to Change the height of the carousel slider bootstarp, I have tired to put a fixed height to the images in pixel but it doesn't work and i have tired to put a fixed height as well to the ID bs-carousel but it doesn't work and as well the the item slides.

```css
.btn.btn-lg {
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.btn.btn-hero,
.btn.btn-hero:hover,
.btn.btn-hero:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #46c3ff;
  border-color: #46c3ff;
  outline: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(http://evisax.com/img/dubai.png);
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(http://evisax.com/img/free_singapore_tour_900.jpg);
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(http://evisax.com/img/Taj_Mahal.png);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .hero {
    width: 980px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .hero h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <div class="slide-1"></div>
      <div class="hero">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-2"></div>
      <div class="hero">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-3"></div>
      <div class="hero">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `!important` to change height

```
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use **px** instead of **Vh** for the following

```
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100px; 
}
```

[FIDDLE-DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Dhanissh05/qxw4hdLf/#tidy)

Comment: It doesnt change anything

Comment: only the image has been resized but the slider still 100%